# Sending image file using WCF

Tags: android, wcf

I am trying to send an image from android client to .NET based server, I am doing it using HTTP POST, will there be any significant difference if I use a stream for file upload or send the data as a base64 string, ie convert the string into base64, send and at the server side convert the base64 string back to image, what difference does it make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few (small) advantages to streaming instead of converting to base64. One is that the conversion to base64 will increase the byte load by about 30% going over the wire. Then there's the extra processing (and programming) involved in the conversion at both ends.

Having said that, I'd recommend base64 over streaming because, in the end, the programming will be much easier I think. Boxing up and sending an HTTP message, even if it contains a boat-load of base64 characters, should be child's play compared to getting that whole stream-send/stream-response business working on Android, right? How hard is it to concatenate into JSON a big string of characters? That's why I'd go with base64.